# Pointer to pointer dereference; Compiler asking for '->'

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

I write an simple function to insert an sub-list to the linked-list given by reference. The code looks correct for me, but compiler directs me that I did not used the pointer correctly.

```
void insertSub(string h, day d, string gr, string sub, ListAPI **tmp_api) {
  auto newNode = new _ListSub;

  // initialize new node of sub-list
  newNode->h = h;
  newNode->d = d;
  newNode->gr = gr;
  newNode->sub = sub;

  // point new node to the previous and next node
  newNode->next = node->next;
  newNode->prev = node;

  // point actual node to the new node
  *tmp_api->head->next->prev = newNode;
  *tmp_api->head->next = newNode;

  cout << "New node inserted to " << *tmp_api->id << endl;

  // increment size
  ++ node->size;
}
```

In some caller function I use it like:

```
auto tmp_api = api;
insertSub( h, (day)enumerateDay(week), gr, sub, &tmp_api );
```

Where `api` is of type `ListAPI *` and does contains nodes.

g++ errors:

```
../src/main.cpp:107:13: error: request for member ‘head’ in ‘* tmp_api’, which is of pointer type ‘ListAPI*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
   *tmp_api->head->next->prev = newNode;
             ^~~~
../src/main.cpp:108:13: error: request for member ‘head’ in ‘* tmp_api’, which is of pointer type ‘ListAPI*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
   *tmp_api->head->next = newNode;
             ^~~~
../src/main.cpp:110:51: error: request for member ‘id’ in ‘* tmp_api’, which is of pointer type ‘ListAPI*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
   cout << "  $ newNode inserted to " << *tmp_api->id << endl;
```

Comment: We'd need to see how you defined `ListAPI`, but it seems odd that `head` would be a member of the struct.  SUGGESTION: compare your code with this example: http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists.

Comment: You have operator precedence problems. Write `(*tmp_api)->head`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As seen [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the `->` operator has a higher priority than the `*` operator, so it gets evaluated first. Use `(*temp_api)->head`.